# Odd Light Seams

Tags: light

I am continuing my work through Blender Foundations and ran into an odd line of light in my render (which you can see to the left of the light on the floor and extending up the wall).  Additionally, the corner of the wall has a small fleck of light on the floor that I can't seem to get rid of.

These can be seen here:

[image]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7r96xt99y3ihdg0/Blend%2020.png?dl=0

The blend is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2m5gyuw0ptyijc/Flower%20020.blend?dl=0

Thank you!

Comment: To link images please use the built in tools for this site. Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Answer (score 1):

I think that there's a gap between your walls and ceiling. Light is passing trough those. And your light system is weird. Do you really all those ten light sources?

Edit: Go to your Spot.008 and change the shadow type do Ray Shadow.

I don't know what is causing the problem but that seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm following Roland Hess' Blender Foundations book.  Interesting that ray shadow fixes it!  I will take a look at the ceiling and see if there's something I can do there as well.

Comment: I tried fixing the ceiling but it still occurs.  Is there no way to do this without the ray shadows?